# Setting up Javascript order price minimum

Tags: javascript

I am trying to set up a way so that if my total cart's price is under $125, it will charge $125. I have googled multiple ways of getting the order minimum added but nothing works with how this code was set up. Please view the code below:

```
function Recalculate() {
  var total = 0;
  $.each(cart, function(index, item) {
    var options = {};
    if (item.o) $.each(item.o, function(opt_ind, opt_item) {
      options[opt_item.name] = opt_item.value;
      options[opt_item.id] = opt_item.value;
    });

    var width_ft = parseInt(options.width_ft);
    if (!width_ft || isNaN(width_ft)) width_ft = 0;

    var width_in = parseInt(options.width_in);
    if (!width_in || isNaN(width_in)) width_in = 0;

    var width = width_ft + width_in / 12;

    var length_ft = parseInt(options.length_ft);
    if (!length_ft || isNaN(length_ft)) length_ft = 0;

    var length_in = parseInt(options.length_in);
    if (!length_in || isNaN(length_in)) length_in = 0;

    var sq = width * length;
    var inshop = options.type_of_cleaning == 'In_Shop_Cleaning';

    var base_price = 0;
    var base_min = 0;
    switch (item.p) {
      case 'livingroom':
        base_price = LIVING_ROOM;
        break; 
      case 'stair':
        base_price = STAIR;
        break;
    }

    var i_total = sq * base_price;
    if (i_total < base_min) i_total = base_min;
    $('span.isize').eq(index).html('$' + i_total.toFixed(2));
    total += i_total;

    if (options.SCOTCHGARD == 'on') total += Math.min(sq * SCOTCHGARD, 25.00);
    if (options.DECON == 'on') total += Math.min(sq * DECON, 25.00);
    if (options.DA == 'on') total += Math.min(sq * DA, 25.00);
    if (options.clean_or_buy == 'buy') total += i_total * NEW_PAD_TAX / 100;

  });
  return [total];
}
```

Comment: how should look like the result, you expect?

Comment: You've included your code, but not the error or expected input/output. It's very difficult for us to debug a problem with that information as well.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to charge a minimum of $125, the simplest thing you could do is simply set the total to that minimum just before you return it. e.g.

```
if (total < 125) { total = 125; }
return total;
```

*(Note that this is returning `total` not `[total]`, as it is not clear to me why you want an array of a single value returned.)*

Your question includes the phrase "...getting the order minimum added". That doesn't make sense to me, i.e. if the real total is $100, I doubt that you want to ***add*** $125 (to make $225 total), but rather you simply want to set the total to the minimum. If that is correct, but you do want to keep track of the extra that you add, then perhaps you could do the following, again right before you return from the function:

```
var extraForMinimum = 0;
if (total < 125) { extraForMinimum = 125 - total; }
return {total: total, extraForMinimum: extraForMinimum };
```

In this case, the function is returning an object that contains both the actual total (which could still be less than $125) as well as the extra cost that is required to bring the charge up to the minimum. If you are doing this, however, you might want to change the variable name from `total` to, say, `subtotal` or something else similar.